# QGIS DXF - Import does not use the Windows fonts

Tags: qgis, import, dxf

The [integrated DXF import](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?#importing-a-dxf-or-dwg-file) didn't use the fonts installed in Windows (for special symbols).

These can be used in QGIS, but the import doesn't use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the font information in the "style" column.
Use this information for styling.
[image]

Use the following code to adjust all layers:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.geometryType() == 0 and layer.name() == 'texts':
        labeling = layer.labeling().clone()
        settings = labeling.settings()
        prop=settings.dataDefinedProperties()
        p=prop.property(QgsPalLayerSettings.Family)

        p.setField('style')

        settings.dataDefinedProperties().setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Family, p)
        labeling.setSettings(settings)
        layer.setLabeling(labeling)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the font information in the Style field is incorrect, instead of "Symbolism 1" "Symbolism 100" is imported. Apparently all fonts do this (always appends a "00". If I change this in the attribute table, it works. 
The problem could be inside the DXF:

symbolism 100
symbolism-1.ttf