# QGIS DXF - Import Script to use the Windows fonts

Tags: pyqgis, import, dxf

I can find the font information in the "style" column and I use this for styling.

The following code adjust all layers:

```
 from qgis.core import QgsProject

 for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():

    if layer.geometryType() == 0 and layer.name() == 'texts':
        labeling = layer.labeling().clone()
        settings = labeling.settings()
        prop=settings.dataDefinedProperties()
        p=prop.property(QgsPalLayerSettings.Family)

        p.setField('style')

        settings.dataDefinedProperties().setProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Family, p)
        labeling.setSettings(settings)
        layer.setLabeling(labeling)
```

But how can I use

```
left("style",regexp_match("style",'00')-1)
```

instead of

```
p.setField('style')
```

in the above code?

Because the information in the Style field is slightly wrong (symbolism 100 instead symbolism-1.ttf).

I got the original code from this post. Maybe this can help.

[QGIS DXF - Import does not use the Windows fonts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445176/qgis-dxf-import-does-not-use-the-windows-fonts?rq=1)